# Can not send information from PHP form to multiple mysql database tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into 4 tables ( asset, asset_details, invoice and location). When I submit the form, it tells me that all the data has been submitted successfully but when I check the MySQL database the information is only submitted to the location tables.

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you .

```
    mysql_query("START TRANSITION");

    $query1 =("INSERT INTO .asset (asset_tag, asset_number, cap_ex, asset_type_id, invoice_id, status) 
        Values(".$_POST['asset_tag'] .",,,".$_POST['asset_type'] . ",".$_POST['invoice_number']."," . $_POST['status_id'] .")");

    $query2 =("INSERT INTO .asset_details (asset_type_id, asset_tag, asset_type, physical_asset_id, manufacturer, os, os_version, make, model, serial_number, processor, ram, memory, hdd, host_name, notes)
        Values(" .",".$_POST['asset_tag']."," .$_POST['asset_type'].",,
        ,".$_POST['os'].",".$_POST['os_version'].",".$_POST['make'].",".$_POST['model'].",".$_POST['serial_number'].",".$_POST['processor'].",,".$_POST['memory'].",".$_POST['hdd'].",,".$_POST['notes'].")");

    $query3 =( "INSERT INTO .invoice (invoice_number, invoice_date, purchas_price, quantity, order_date, vender, warrenty_end, notes)   
        Values(" .$_POST['invoice_number'].",". $_POST['invoice_date'].",". $_POST['purchase_price'].",,,". $_POST['vender'].")");

    $query4 =( "INSERT INTO .location (location_name, rack, row, unit)
        Values(" .$_POST['location_name'].",".$_POST['rack'].",".$_POST['row'].",".$_POST['unit'].")");

    echo "$query1 $query2 $query3 $query4";


    $result1= mysql_query($query1);
    $result2= mysql_query($query2);
    $result3= mysql_query($query3);
    $result4= mysql_query($query4);

    $result = mysql_query("COMMIT");    

if (!$result)
{
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('SUCCESS!');</script>";
}
}


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: There are no quotes around your string values! What does the echo $query... produce?

Comment: How did you come up with `mysql_query("START TRANSITION");`...

Comment: shouldn't it be `mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");`?

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*` anymore. Use `PDO` oder `mysqli_*` instead when writing new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some strange things;

- `START TRANSITION` should probably be `START TRANSACTION`.
- You're not quoting any of your string values. Strings need to be quoted using `'` a'la `INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('olle');`
- An empty field cannot be indicated by just skipping it, you're doing `INSERT INTO TEST (a,b,c) VALUES (1,,2);` which is not valid syntax for not setting b.

Also, I recommend using a more modern mysql api than `mysql_query`, as for example [PDO or mysqli](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/), since injecting POST values into a string as you do can be pretty dangerous, you may cause SQL injection problems.

Comment: Sorry but I am new to mySQL and PHP and am not sure about the correct syntax to your 3rd point. " An empty field cannot be indicated by just skipping it, you're doing INSERT INTO TEST (a,b,c) VALUES (1,,2); which is not valid syntax for not setting b."

Answer (score 0):

Use '`'s around each attributes(columns) and ''' around each values, it should work

During development, I'd echo each query-expressions before it is sent to the database..

...by the way, mysql_error() is a useful function in php, which returns the last error information of mysql....U may use that for debugging